# Поиск текущего значения растущей величины

Tags: алгоритм, математика, машинное-обучение

Целочисленная величина в социальной сети постоянно растёт в результате активности пользователей. Задача – находить её значение на настоящий момент.

Нет методов API для получения текущего значения, но можно узнавать «достигнуто ли уже значение X?» — true / false. Обнаружив цепочку (true,false) можно сказать, что мы нашли наибольшее на сегодня значение в позиции, где true. Число вызовов API требуется минимизировать.

Сейчас реализовал топорно: последнее найденное значение Low на начало недели жестко прописывается в коде (не делайте так!). Есть предположение, что за неделю значение не может вырасти больше, чем на 2 млн. Двоичный поиск в диапазоне `Low .. Low + 2e6` отыскивает текущий максимум. Каждую неделю приходится обновлять код новым найденным максимальным значением. Lame, я знаю ) Это был быстрый эксперимент на коленке, который настало время сделать чуть умнее.

По имеющимся за неск. месяцев наблюдениям можно построить приближённую линейную модель прогноза роста, или гиперболическую (больше людей присоединяется к сети – быстрее растёт величина).

Хочется сделать этот инструмент полностью автономным. Однажды заложить в код найденные на сегодня параметры и отпустить в свободное плавание. Человек скачал себе приложение - дальше локально собирает собственную коллекцию статистики, на основе которой корректируется гипотеза текущего значения и в каком диапазоне его искать. Чем больше времени прошло с последних измерений – тем шире диапазон поиска.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получил гиперболу, которая хорошо вписывается в имеющиеся данные. Пусть на 90% училась, 10% хорошо угадывает, хотя тут далеко не bigdata. Прошло какое-то время после последнего измерения, и на текущий момент модель даёт значение H. Как вычислить диапазон поиска (H-D; H+D), в котором искать; и как этот диапазон расширять, если окажется, что значение вне его? Накинуть ещё D, или D/2?

Answer (score 1):

Вижу два сценария развития событий. Первый сценарий работает, когда «тема не пошла» — сначала всплеск, потом падение. Второй сценарий, когда «тема пошла», должен давать S-образную кривую, с ускорением роста в первой половине и замедлением во второй.

Сначала обсудим S-образный сценарий.

Чтобы быстрее найти новое значение показателя нам нужно высокоточное предсказание этого значения. Фактически, мы говорим об *экстраполяции* имеющихся данных. S-образному росту соответствуют *кривая Гомперца* и *логистическая кривая* ([сам погуглил](http://masters.donntu.org/2006/kita/kiryan/library/art02.htm)). Для предсказания, мы сначала рассчитываем коэффициенты уравнения, опираясь на предыдущие значения. Затем, подставив коэффициенты в формулу, рассчитываем значение функции в новой точке.

С помощью предсказания, мы начинаем поиск нового точного значения. Если значение не попадает в указанный диапазон, этот диапазон надо расширить. Ваши данные нелинейные, поэтому каждый раз накидывая `D` вы рискуете долго добираться до новых значений. Иными словами,  арифметическая прогрессия `[H-D, H+D], [H-2D, H+2D], [H-3D, H+3D], [H-4D, H+4D]` — слишком медленно, используйте геометрическую `[H-D, H+D], [H-2D, H+2D], [H-4D, H+4D], [H-8D, H+8D]`.

Реализовав эту схему, можем встроить в неё сценарий №1 — «тема не пошла». Если исторические данные показывают падение, переключаемся на другой режим расчёта. Не знаю точно, какая модель лучше всего подойдёт для данного случая. Мне кажется, гипербола не хуже прочих, можно оставить её.

Теперь о том, как начинать. Не имея никакой информации о начальном значении, начинать можно с любого значения. Но, если будете собирать все данные в одном месте, будете знать, какие начальные значения встречаются, и можете начинать от среднего.